# JWPlayer JS plugin added to the flash-version

Tags: javascript, plugins, jwplayer

I modified a plugin to JWPlayer(http://www.pluginsbyethan.com/newsticker6.html), which ended up working great on the HTML5 version with mp4 format playing, but when i shifts to Flash version, it crashes the player.

How come I can't implement the plugin on the Flash version?

If I use a callback to a .swf file, that is not relevant, it does not crash, so does the Flash player only support .swf flash plugins, or can I define the JS plugin to the Flash player somehow?

Code looks like this;

```
jwplayer().registerPlugin("ticker", "6.0", function(player, config) {

    function setup() {
            var theBody = document.getElementById(player.id);

            var playerWidthPX2 = player.getHeight();
            var playerWidthPX = parseFloat(playerWidthPX2);
            var playerHeightPX2 = player.getWidth();
            var playerHeightPX = parseFloat(playerHeightPX2);

            var ticker_top = document.createElement("div");
            var ticker_top_marquee = document.createElement("marquee");
            var ticker_middle = document.createElement("div");
            var ticker_middle_marquee = document.createElement("marquee");
            var ticker_middle_date = document.createElement("div");

            // top
            ticker_top.setAttribute("id", "ticker_top");
            ticker_top.style.background = "#e3bfa3";
            ticker_top.style.height = 26 + "px";
            ticker_top.style.width = "100%";
            ticker_top.style.position = "absolute";
            ticker_top.style.zIndex = "1";
            ticker_top.style.bottom = "25px";
            ticker_top.style.opacity = "1";
            ticker_top.style.visibility = "hidden";

            // Marquee too ticker_middle
            ticker_top_marquee.setAttribute("id", "ticker_top_marquee");
            ticker_top_marquee.style.color = "#000000";
            ticker_top_marquee.innerHTML = config.ticker1;
            ticker_top_marquee.setAttribute("scrollamount", "6");
            ticker_top_marquee.setAttribute("direction", "left");
            ticker_top_marquee.style.fontSize = "18px";
            ticker_top_marquee.style.fontWeight = "600";
            ticker_top_marquee.style.textTransform = "uppercase";
            ticker_top_marquee.style.cursor = "default";
            ticker_top_marquee.style.fontFamily = "PT Sans";
            ticker_top_marquee.style.position = "absolute";
            ticker_top_marquee.style.zIndex = "2";
            ticker_top_marquee.style.width = "100%";
            ticker_top_marquee.style.bottom = "23px";
            ticker_top_marquee.style.visibility = "hidden";
            ticker_top_marquee.style.opacity = "1";

            // middle
            ticker_middle.setAttribute("id", "ticker_middle");
            ticker_middle.style.background = "#000000";
            ticker_middle.style.height = 25 + "px";
            ticker_middle.style.width = "100%";
            ticker_middle.style.position = "absolute";
            ticker_middle.style.zIndex = "1";
            ticker_middle.style.bottom = "0px";
            ticker_middle.style.opacity = "1";
            ticker_middle.style.visibility = "hidden";

            // Marquee too ticker_middle
            ticker_middle_marquee.setAttribute("id", "ticker_middle_marquee");
            ticker_middle_marquee.style.color = "#ec008b";
            ticker_middle_marquee.innerHTML = config.ticker2;
            ticker_middle_marquee.setAttribute("scrollamount", "7");
            ticker_middle_marquee.setAttribute("direction", "left");
            ticker_middle_marquee.style.fontSize = "16px";
            ticker_middle_marquee.style.fontWeight = "600";
            ticker_middle_marquee.style.cursor = "default";
            ticker_middle_marquee.style.fontFamily = "PT Sans";
            ticker_middle_marquee.style.position = "absolute";
            ticker_middle_marquee.style.zIndex = "3";
            ticker_middle_marquee.style.width = "100%";
            ticker_middle_marquee.style.textTransform = "uppercase";
            ticker_middle_marquee.style.bottom = "0px";
            ticker_middle_marquee.style.visibility = "hidden";
            ticker_middle_marquee.style.opacity = "1";

            // middle date
            ticker_middle_date.setAttribute("id", "ticker_middle_date");
            ticker_middle_date.style.background = "#FFF";
            ticker_middle_date.style.height = 25 + "px";
            ticker_middle_date.style.width = "100px";
            ticker_middle_date.style.position = "absolute";
            ticker_middle_date.style.fontSize = "16px";
            ticker_middle_date.style.textAlign = "center";
            ticker_middle_date.style.fontWeight = "600";
            ticker_middle_date.style.cursor = "default";
            ticker_middle_date.style.fontFamily = "PT Sans";
            ticker_middle_date.style.zIndex = "3";
            ticker_middle_date.style.bottom = "0px";
            ticker_middle_date.style.left = "0px";
            ticker_middle_date.style.opacity = "1";
            ticker_middle_date.style.visibility = "hidden";
            ticker_middle_date.innerHTML = config.date;

            theBody.onmouseover = function(){
                ticker_top.style.visibility = "hidden";
                ticker_top_marquee.style.visibility = "hidden";
                ticker_middle.style.visibility = "hidden";
                ticker_middle_marquee.style.visibility = "hidden";
                ticker_middle_date.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
            theBody.onmouseout = function(){
                ticker_top.style.visibility = "visible";
                ticker_top_marquee.style.visibility = "visible";
                ticker_middle.style.visibility = "visible";
                ticker_middle_marquee.style.visibility = "visible";
                ticker_middle_date.style.visibility = "visible";

            }

            //Append it
            theBody.appendChild(ticker_top);
            theBody.appendChild(ticker_top_marquee);
            theBody.appendChild(ticker_middle);
            theBody.appendChild(ticker_middle_marquee);
            theBody.appendChild(ticker_middle_date);

    }

    player.onReady(setup);

    player.onPlay(function() {
        var ticker_top = document.getElementById('ticker_top');
        var ticker_top_marquee = document.getElementById('ticker_top_marquee');
        var ticker_middle = document.getElementById('ticker_middle');
        var ticker_middle_marquee = document.getElementById('ticker_middle_marquee');
        var ticker_middle_date = document.getElementById('ticker_middle_date');

        ticker_top.style.visibility = "visible";
        ticker_top_marquee.style.visibility = "visible";
        ticker_middle.style.visibility = "visible";
        ticker_middle_marquee.style.visibility = "visible";
        ticker_middle_date.style.visibility = "visible";
    });

    this.resize = function() {
        var ticker_top = document.getElementById('ticker_top');
        var ticker_top_marquee = document.getElementById('ticker_top_marquee');
        var ticker_middle = document.getElementById('ticker_middle');
        var ticker_middle_marquee = document.getElementById('ticker_middle_marquee');
        var ticker_middle_date = document.getElementById('ticker_middle_date');

        if(player.getFullscreen() == true){
            ticker_top.style.visibility = "visible";
            ticker_top_marquee.style.visibility = "visible";
            ticker_middle.style.visibility = "visible";
            ticker_middle_marquee.style.visibility = "visible";
            ticker_middle_date.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        // if(player.getFullscreen() == false){
        //  ticker_top.style.visibility = "hidden";
        //  ticker_top_marquee.style.visibility = "hidden";
        //  ticker_middle.style.visibility = "hidden";
        //  ticker_middle_marquee.style.visibility = "hidden";
        //  ticker_middle_date.style.visibility = "hidden";
        // }
    }

}, '');
```

Thanks, stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you modified my plugin here - http://www.pluginsbyethan.com/newsticker6.html

This plugin was originally written in Flash, so the JS version falls back to the Flash version like so:

```
}, 'newsticker.swf');
```

You removed the swf in the quotes, but now the JS plugin is trying to fall back to a swf file that doesn't exist:

```
}, '');
```

Also, in Flash mode, the player has a wrapper id added to it.

Here is some updated code that doesn't have any sort of Flash fallback, which seems to work:

```
(function(jwplayer) {
    var template = function(player, config, ticker) {
        function setup(evt) {
            if (player.getRenderingMode() == "html5") {
                var theBody = document.getElementById(player.id);
            } else {
                var theBody = document.getElementById(player.id + "_wrapper");
            }

                        var playerWidthPX2 = player.getHeight();
                        var playerWidthPX = parseFloat(playerWidthPX2);
                        var playerHeightPX2 = player.getWidth();
                        var playerHeightPX = parseFloat(playerHeightPX2);

                        var ticker_top = document.createElement("div");
                        var ticker_top_marquee = document.createElement("marquee");
                        var ticker_middle = document.createElement("div");
                        var ticker_middle_marquee = document.createElement("marquee");
                        var ticker_middle_date = document.createElement("div");

                        // top
                        ticker_top.setAttribute("id", "ticker_top");
                        ticker_top.style.background = "#e3bfa3";
                        ticker_top.style.height = 26 + "px";
                        ticker_top.style.width = "100%";
                        ticker_top.style.position = "absolute";
                        ticker_top.style.zIndex = "1";
                        ticker_top.style.bottom = "25px";
                        ticker_top.style.opacity = "1";
                        ticker_top.style.visibility = "hidden";

                        // Marquee too ticker_middle
                        ticker_top_marquee.setAttribute("id", "ticker_top_marquee");
                        ticker_top_marquee.style.color = "#000000";
                        ticker_top_marquee.innerHTML = config.ticker1;
                        ticker_top_marquee.setAttribute("scrollamount", "6");
                        ticker_top_marquee.setAttribute("direction", "left");
                        ticker_top_marquee.style.fontSize = "18px";
                        ticker_top_marquee.style.fontWeight = "600";
                        ticker_top_marquee.style.textTransform = "uppercase";
                        ticker_top_marquee.style.cursor = "default";
                        ticker_top_marquee.style.fontFamily = "PT Sans";
                        ticker_top_marquee.style.position = "absolute";
                        ticker_top_marquee.style.zIndex = "2";
                        ticker_top_marquee.style.width = "100%";
                        ticker_top_marquee.style.bottom = "23px";
                        ticker_top_marquee.style.visibility = "hidden";
                        ticker_top_marquee.style.opacity = "1";

                        // middle
                        ticker_middle.setAttribute("id", "ticker_middle");
                        ticker_middle.style.background = "#000000";
                        ticker_middle.style.height = 25 + "px";
                        ticker_middle.style.width = "100%";
                        ticker_middle.style.position = "absolute";
                        ticker_middle.style.zIndex = "1";
                        ticker_middle.style.bottom = "0px";
                        ticker_middle.style.opacity = "1";
                        ticker_middle.style.visibility = "hidden";

                        // Marquee too ticker_middle
                        ticker_middle_marquee.setAttribute("id", "ticker_middle_marquee");
                        ticker_middle_marquee.style.color = "#ec008b";
                        ticker_middle_marquee.innerHTML = config.ticker2;
                        ticker_middle_marquee.setAttribute("scrollamount", "7");
                        ticker_middle_marquee.setAttribute("direction", "left");
                        ticker_middle_marquee.style.fontSize = "16px";
                        ticker_middle_marquee.style.fontWeight = "600";
                        ticker_middle_marquee.style.cursor = "default";
                        ticker_middle_marquee.style.fontFamily = "PT Sans";
                        ticker_middle_marquee.style.position = "absolute";
                        ticker_middle_marquee.style.zIndex = "3";
                        ticker_middle_marquee.style.width = "100%";
                        ticker_middle_marquee.style.textTransform = "uppercase";
                        ticker_middle_marquee.style.bottom = "0px";
                        ticker_middle_marquee.style.visibility = "hidden";
                        ticker_middle_marquee.style.opacity = "1";

                        // middle date
                        ticker_middle_date.setAttribute("id", "ticker_middle_date");
                        ticker_middle_date.style.background = "#FFF";
                        ticker_middle_date.style.height = 25 + "px";
                        ticker_middle_date.style.width = "100px";
                        ticker_middle_date.style.position = "absolute";
                        ticker_middle_date.style.fontSize = "16px";
                        ticker_middle_date.style.textAlign = "center";
                        ticker_middle_date.style.fontWeight = "600";
                        ticker_middle_date.style.cursor = "default";
                        ticker_middle_date.style.fontFamily = "PT Sans";
                        ticker_middle_date.style.zIndex = "3";
                        ticker_middle_date.style.bottom = "0px";
                        ticker_middle_date.style.left = "0px";
                        ticker_middle_date.style.opacity = "1";
                        ticker_middle_date.style.visibility = "hidden";
                        ticker_middle_date.innerHTML = config.date;

                        theBody.onmouseover = function(){
                            ticker_top.style.visibility = "hidden";
                            ticker_top_marquee.style.visibility = "hidden";
                            ticker_middle.style.visibility = "hidden";
                            ticker_middle_marquee.style.visibility = "hidden";
                            ticker_middle_date.style.visibility = "hidden";
                        }
                        theBody.onmouseout = function(){
                            ticker_top.style.visibility = "visible";
                            ticker_top_marquee.style.visibility = "visible";
                            ticker_middle.style.visibility = "visible";
                            ticker_middle_marquee.style.visibility = "visible";
                            ticker_middle_date.style.visibility = "visible";

                        }

                        //Append it
                        theBody.appendChild(ticker_top);
                        theBody.appendChild(ticker_top_marquee);
                        theBody.appendChild(ticker_middle);
                        theBody.appendChild(ticker_middle_marquee);
                        theBody.appendChild(ticker_middle_date);
        };
        player.onReady(setup);

        player.onReady(setup);

    player.onPlay(function() {
        var ticker_top = document.getElementById('ticker_top');
        var ticker_top_marquee = document.getElementById('ticker_top_marquee');
        var ticker_middle = document.getElementById('ticker_middle');
        var ticker_middle_marquee = document.getElementById('ticker_middle_marquee');
        var ticker_middle_date = document.getElementById('ticker_middle_date');

        ticker_top.style.visibility = "visible";
        ticker_top_marquee.style.visibility = "visible";
        ticker_middle.style.visibility = "visible";
        ticker_middle_marquee.style.visibility = "visible";
        ticker_middle_date.style.visibility = "visible";
    });

    this.resize = function() {
        var ticker_top = document.getElementById('ticker_top');
        var ticker_top_marquee = document.getElementById('ticker_top_marquee');
        var ticker_middle = document.getElementById('ticker_middle');
        var ticker_middle_marquee = document.getElementById('ticker_middle_marquee');
        var ticker_middle_date = document.getElementById('ticker_middle_date');

        if(player.getFullscreen() == true){
            ticker_top.style.visibility = "visible";
            ticker_top_marquee.style.visibility = "visible";
            ticker_middle.style.visibility = "visible";
            ticker_middle_marquee.style.visibility = "visible";
            ticker_middle_date.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        // if(player.getFullscreen() == false){
        //  ticker_top.style.visibility = "hidden";
        //  ticker_top_marquee.style.visibility = "hidden";
        //  ticker_middle.style.visibility = "hidden";
        //  ticker_middle_marquee.style.visibility = "hidden";
        //  ticker_middle_date.style.visibility = "hidden";
        // }
    }

    };
    jwplayer().registerPlugin('ticker', '6.0', template);
})(jwplayer);
```

Comment: Yes, I modified your awesome plugin. Thanks for posting it on github, and sorry for not mentioning your awesome work. 

Yes, this works great! Thanks!

Comment: It worked great, but when you fullscreen flash, the tickers does not show. Is there another container, or something I can't figure out? Mp4 and html5 still works great. :)

Comment: Great, no problem! :) Ah yes, that is because in Flash full screen mode, you really can't overlay JS/HTML on top. That is why making a Flash plugin is helpful, since HTML5/JS won't work when full screen mode is used.

Comment: Damn it. Hoped I could get around coding ActionScript. I been modifing your Newsticker.as file, but when i export it, it won't work at all. Even if I dont change anything in it. How come? I can't see any errors, and I made sure it got jwplayer-6-lib.swc connected to it.

Comment: How are you compiling? You really only need the SWF for fullscreen mode in Flash.

Comment: I couldn't get the compiler in Flash Pro to work. So I ended up using the .bat in the jwplayer sdks -> jw6-plugin-sdk in APItester instead. Hope this can help anyone else. Got it to work. :) Thanks Ethan.